# MySQL Logs Table Query to fetch changed data

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

unfortunately I am stuck at some point and can't move forward.
Let me describe what is the problem.

Short description: I wrote a system that constantly check status of servers, the results are 1 or 0 (true of false). Those statuses are being written to database table named "logs". There are multiple monitored systems. Now what I want to achieve is fetch from database list of status changes for each system. (Only when the status changed for ex. went from online to offline) for all the period of data.

Structure:

```
Table [logs] -
logs.logs_id == mon.mon_id
logs.logs_status 
logs.logs_updated

Table [monitoring] -
mon.mon_id
mon.mon_sid
mon.....
```

Example data -

```
logs.logs_id | logs.logs_status | logs.logs_updated
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:00
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:00
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:00
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:00
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:00
6    0    2020/02/29 21:04:00
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:10
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:10
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:10
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:10
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:10
6    0    2020/02/29 21:04:10
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:20
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:20
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:20
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:20
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:20
6    0    2020/02/29 21:04:20
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
6    1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
6    1    2020/02/29 21:04:40
1    1    2020/02/29 21:04:50
2    1    2020/02/29 21:04:50
3    1    2020/02/29 21:04:50
4    1    2020/02/29 21:04:50
5    1    2020/02/29 21:04:50
6    0    2020/02/29 21:04:50
1    1    2020/02/29 21:05:00
2    1    2020/02/29 21:05:00
3    1    2020/02/29 21:05:00
4    1    2020/02/29 21:05:00
5    0    2020/02/29 21:05:00
6    0    2020/02/29 21:05:00
```

Based on above example data I would like to create SQL Query (MySQL Database) that will show below results -

```
mon.mon_sid | logs.logs_status | logs.logs_updated
YYY        0    2020/02/29 21:05:00
XXX        0    2020/02/29 21:04:50
XXX        1    2020/02/29 21:04:30
XXX        0    2020/02/29 21:04:00
```

Since only status of log.mon_id == 6 and log.mon_id == 5 has been changed as per data, then only this should be returned. So I will have four rows results.

Thank you in advance for assistance, I am so exhausted trying to figure it out.
Greets, Michael.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Hi @GMB, thank you for answer. It's version 8.0.19. I am checking your answer right now.

Comment: Hi hapvlz, be sure to use indices on this table. If you use "partition by" you should have the columns used for partitioning in an index for faster lookup. Otherwise your select statement could become rather expensive and slow.

Comment: Hi boys, im under impression, but solution proposed by GMB actually meet my expectations and can fit to that what I want to achieve.

Regarding to your suggestion @DwightKendall, thank you for pointing out also performance perspective. I am not 100% sure how to realize your words in practice. Table has 4 columns.

logs_snapshot
mon_id
logs_status
logs_updated

no-one of above is primary key or index.
Do you suggesting to add also index column with primary unique key which will increase with each row? This table will have HUGE amount of data. So I need to consider your suggestion.

Comment: So far works like a charm!! Thank you so much @GMB for that solution.
here screen from tests, https://i.imgur.com/crTkCsx.png

DwightKendall, if you would willing to explain more I would also appreciate a lot. I might be very important soon.

Comment: Hi hapvlz. I have to revoke my previous comment. In my experiments at home I noticed that the lag function is far more optimized than I thought.
I even tried to come up with a solution that uses an index and joins, but all tries were slower by factor ~2 compared to lag function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just use `lag()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        l.*,
        lag(logs_status) over(
            partition by logs_id 
            order by logs_updated
        ) lag_log_status
    from logs l
) t
where log_status <> lag_log_status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    mon.mon_sid,
    mon.mon_hostname,
    mon.mon_port,
    mon.mon_display,
    logs_status AS current_status,
    previous_status,
    logs_updated
from (
    select 
        l.*,
        lag(logs_status) over(
            partition by mon_id
            order by logs_updated
        ) previous_status
    from logs l
) tmp
    INNER JOIN monitoring AS mon
    ON tmp.mon_id = mon.mon_id
where logs_status <> previous_status
ORDER BY logs_updated DESC
```

This is the final version based on @GMB Solution, thank you again @GMB.